# Design a Li-Po battery charger with small solar panel and charger controller with embedded MPPT

Tags: battery-charging, zener, mppt, solar-charge-controller

I'm designing a small solar charger with these characteristics:

**SOLAR PANEL**

- Voc = 5,65 V
- Vmp = 4,25 V (Voc -25% approx.)
- Isc = 250 mA

**IC CHARGER CONTROLLER**

STMicroelectronics [SPV1040](http://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/spv1040.pdf) High efficiency solar battery charger with embedded MPPT

**BATTERY**

- Type Li-Po (Model LP804367, FULLWAT)
- Nominal Voltage 3.7 V
- Nominal Capacity 2400 mAh
- Standard Charge Current 480 mA
- Max Charge Current 4800 mA
- Charge cut-off Voltage 4.20+/-0.05 V
- Discharge cut-off Voltage 2.75 V

I used the ST Electronics eDesignSuite tool and THIS is the schematic of the design calculated with this tool
[image]

**QUESTIONS**

When I have entered the characteristics of the solar panel in the eDesignSuite tool, I have introduced as open circuit voltage the value Voc = 5.2 V which is the maximum input voltage allowed by the IC SPV1040T. However, the Voc value of the solar panel used is 5.65 V, so I thought of using a zener diode in parallel with the capacitor Cin to not exceed this the maximum voltage allowed at the IC input (5.2 V).

1. Is this correct or is there a better solution than using a zener diode to clamp the input voltage?
2. Could the zener diode decrease to the efficiency of the MPPT algorithm?
3. If using a diode zener is a feasible solution, could this zener diode be used? ([1SMA5918BT3G](http://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/1SMA5913BT3-D.PDF))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, that chip is largely unsuitable for your needs. It is a boost converter i.e. generates an output voltage that is higher than the input supply voltage. Given that your SP ranges between 4.25 volts and 5.65 volts AND you only require a maximum output voltage of 4.2 volts, you should be looking for a buck (rather than boost) controller.

The block diagram below shows the transistors that prove to me it's a boost converter: -

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Do you know any buck controller charger for solar power source? As much as I look for I do not find any for the characteristics of my design.

Comment: @FranMartin it's not an area I have had much experience in so nothing springs to mind.